# How to Cascade ElementCollection in JPA (eclipselink)

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

EclipseLink 4.2, Glassfish, JavaEE6

I am looking for the equivalent of @OnUpdateCascade annotation for EclipseLink, as this annotation does not exist (why?).
I am modifying the email of a user, of which a foreign key in another table, 'user_groups', references. As such I get a MySQL foreign key constraint error. I can't find anyway around this except manually altering the foreign key index to include 'ON UPDATE CASCADE'.
Any alternative methods, or even a reason the functionality doesn't exist (@OnDeleteCascade exists) would be a appreciated.

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Group.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
    @CollectionTable(name = "users_groups",
            joinColumns =
            @JoinColumn(name = "email", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "email"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "groupname", nullable = false)
    private List<Group> groups;
}
```

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that the Group is just an enum? Is there a reason to join over the email, which is mutable, instead of joining using the id?

Comment: Yes the group is just an enum. The authentication framework I'm using looks for the roles of a user in the users_groups table by searching for the credential (which is the email, not the id, of the user).  So I need to have an email column in the users_groups table.

Comment: JPA only allows references to use primary keys, so an onUpdateCascade isn't useful as PKs aren't allowed to change.  EclipseLink does allow non-pk fields to be used in references, so you could file an enhancement request with EclipseLink to have it added